# char c[]="Albus"; printf("%c", c);

Tags: c, char, printf, format-specifiers, c-strings

what will be the output if we try to use `%c` in `printf` while printing  string. For eg-

```
char c[]="Albus";
printf("%c", c);
```

or

```
char c[2]="A";
printf("%c", c);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are some facts about [c](/questions/tagged/c) you're missing:

1. There's no `string` datatype. A string is just a sequence of `char` ending with a `0` byte. What you use here is a string *literal* -- the compiler translates it to an array of `char` and automatically adds the `0` at the end.
2. An array when passed to a function is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, so your `printf()` here gets a parameter of type `char *`.

With this in mind, your code is just undefined behavior: Your format string (`%c`) tells `printf()` to expect a `char`, but it is given a `char *` instead which is a completely different type and  normally has a different size (e.g. 4 bytes on your typical *i386* machine).

What will probably happen in practice is that `printf()` will show the least significant byte of the address of your `char` array, interpreted as an ASCII character. It will look random. But it could also just crash or do whatever else, it's undefined ...

---

For starters, always compile your [c](/questions/tagged/c) code with all compiler warnings enabled. Then you will get warnings about most things that might come out undefined or are dangerous for other reasons. In case you don't understand a warning, google for it.

If you use `gcc`, the way to do it is `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: "_`printf()` will show the least significant byte of the address of your char array, interpreted as an ASCII character_" -- Isn't that dependent on endianess? And Cool Answer! +1

Comment: @CoolGuy I don't think so because a `char` would be passed as an `int`, too ... but of course there's no guarantees anything in particular will happen for UB, tried to make that clear ;)

Comment: For the records, `c` isn't a string literal but an array of `char`.

Comment: @JensGustedt and it's initialized using a string literal. How would you phrase that even *more* clearly?